# PHP fpassthru/fopen call causing "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!" on first attempt

Tags: php, redirect

I am experiencing an intermittent issue with the fpassthru function, where I am being given the following error which is causing me to have to exit out the script. This is the error I am getting:

> Warning:
>   fopen(http://www.devcrm.lan/rw/category/?session_id=29cc6ecc068bcc1a3862cadb8b9d09c5&admin_sess_id=&g_id=W&cat_id=226&d_id=0&pdid=0&sale=0&page=0&position=&slug=womens/sale/&ajax=0&view_all=0&all=0&c_code=RW&u_region=RW&c_id=1&filter_cat_id[]=&filter_size[]=&filter_colour[]=&filter_price[]=&HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%3B+rv%3A10.0.2%29+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F10.0.2&user_http_host=www.devcrm.lan&user_mobile_config=0)
>   [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in
>   /var/www/vhosts/dev/devcrm/shop/index.php on line 213

This is the area of my code where I am using fpassthru. Unfortunately, I am forced to use this function (at the moment, anyway) due to legacy code issues. It is used to send through maintain the $url_parameters when moving from page to page.

```
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'max_redirects' => 5,          
            'timeout'       => 1,
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);

    $fpthruPath = URL . "category/" . $url_parameters;

    $fp = fopen($fpthruPath, 'rb', false, $context);
    if ( false !== $fp ) {
        fpassthru($fp);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    exit();
```

The strange thing about this is that if I take the URL that I am inserting into fopen and stick it in the browser - it works! Also, it only seems to throw this error the *first* time I go to the page. Is this an Apache setting issue?

Comment: So the request is coming back around to the same server? Might be caused by sessions that require mutual exclusion.

Comment: @Yotaware Yes, the request is being made to the same server that the request is made _from_. Is that an Apache setting?

Comment: Are you using PHP sessions? If yes then you cannot load 2 pages that share the same session at the same time. I suggest changing the code so that you don't have to have the additional request. Perhaps you need another question about that.

Comment: I agree it's better to not need this nasty workaround. Your other options are to not start the session in the sub- or main- request, or create a different session-handler that's non-blocking.

Comment: @Yotaware No, i'm not using PHP sessions. That is a session I am using within the code and for database purposes. Is there any reason why this would happen for the _first_ request only and not for any subsequent requests?

Comment: It might be something to do with the url you're requesting. Try changing it to something a bit simpler. eg: http://www.devcrm.lan/rw/category or even just http://www.google.com/ and see what you get back. If that doesn't fix it. Try encoding the url.

Comment: @Elachys The thing is, the URL is valid and when I refresh the page it works! It makes me suspect it is some Apache caching-related issue. I haven't found a solution for it as yet. It is very intermittent and completely random it would seem. Does fopen have issues with URLs that are not encoded?

Comment: Rule out apache, run your php script from the command line.
Another idea: Presuming you're on mac / linux or you have curl installed. Try curl'ing it. Open a terminal and do (trimmed due to content size):
curl -i http://www.devcrm.lan/rw/category/?....
What do you get back? (run it several times if you think it's an intermiten issue). Then try url decoding / encoding it and see what you get.
Since we can't see what the server is responding with. I can't reproduce the setup you have. Which makes this very tricky to solve.

Comment: @Elachys Are you suggesting using something like linx from the command line on the URL that is causing problems?

Comment: Yes. but use curl. that way you can give us the exact response on a normal request to that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after at least a couple of weeks of head-scratching I have found that the 'timeout' HTTP setting I am passing into `stream_context_create` is causing the fopen to fail. When I comment this out I no longer get the *failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!* warning from fopen.

I am not sure, however, why this has become a problem since upgrading to 5.3.10 as this was never an issue when using 5.1.6. I have had a look around for some 5.3 performance posts, but can't find much. Understandably, I have grave concerns over releasing this to a live environment as if something that works in 5.1.6 now struggles, presumably due to the limited timeout, in 5.3.10 then are there performance issues with the newer version of PHP that aren't documented? There have been no other coding changes between the script that fails (intermittently) on 5.3.10, but always works on 5.1.6.

I'm not sure whether to remove the timeout or just increase it to 5 or something like that.

```
$options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'max_redirects' => 5          // stop after 5 redirects
                 // 'timeout'       => 1,         // timeout of 1 second
            )
        );
$context = stream_context_create($options);

$fp = fopen($fpthruPath, 'rb', false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

One time I was fopen'ing a connection to a remote http server. Eventually I discovered there was a load balancer in front of their server cluster. I don't know what they used, but, on the first request, it would *sometimes* issue a redirect to the exact same url, so they could set a cookie with a serverid in it.

I didn't initially bother with sending the cookie back when following the redirect, because it worked without it. One day it *intermittently* started giving me gateway timeouts. Sending the cookie back on the second request solved it.